# How do I disable the toolstripitems on BindingNavigator?

Tags: c#, toolstripitem

I want to enable or disable the toolstripitems on the bindingnavigator programmatically.

When I try to set the toolStripitem's enable property, it does not change. It does not give any exception but the value of Enable property does not change.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BindingNavigator` takes control of these buttons itself, to enable/disable them as appropriate; i.e. you can't go prev/next if there is no more data, you can't add/delete without the underlying source letting you (`IBindingList.AllowNew`/`.AllowRemove`.

Which buttons do you want to tweak? For example, you can disable add/remove by using a data-source such as `BindingList<T>`, and setting `AllowNew=false`/`AllowRemove=false`.

Alternatively, simply write your own buttons completely (forget `BindingNavigator`) - it isn't a lot of work, especially if you start with a `BindingSource` on the form (since that has all the necessary `MoveFirst()` etc.

Comment: Any idea why `BindingSource.AllowEdit` and `BindingSource.AllowRemove` are read-only but `BindingSource.AllowNew` is read-write ?

Comment: @BaltoStar none whatsoever